# Using two linear functions of a 3D random vector to find a plane in which it is concentrated

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let us take three random normal variables and combine them into one which we call $X$. We know their means, variances, and covariances, and thus we can come up with a mean vector and a variance matrix: $$\xi = (0,0,0)^T \ \ \ \\ \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1  & 1 & 0 \\1 & 4 & -3 \\0 & -3 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
I have to answer the following question. I have already answered it using a different method, but I cannot do it using the method described in the question:

> Determine the distribution of \begin{pmatrix} X_1 - X_2 \\ X_3 \end{pmatrix} and use this information to determine a subspace $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $2$ on which $X$ is concentrated with probability $1$.

The method I used was more by brute force and the answer I got was rather ugly.

Comment: Do $X_1$ and $X_3$ determine $X_2$? Both the covariance matrix and the question suggest they do.

Comment: Could you add some detail?

Comment: What you are supposed to do is use the covariance matrix to find the variance of $X_1-X_2$ and its covariance with $X_3$.  That will lead you to an expression relating $X_1,X_2,X_3$ which will turn out to be a plane in $3D$ space

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- What is the covariance of ${X_1-X_2 \choose X_3}$?

Further hints:

- $E[(X_1-X_2)^2] = E[X_1^2]-2E[X_1 X_2] + E[X_2^2]$
- $E[(X_1-X_2) X_3] = E[X_1 X_3]-E[X_2 X_3]$

Comment: Hm. Is there another way to solve this? I don't seem to be getting your clues, and it doesn't seem to be what my teaching assistant was talking about in class (I missed his entire solution, as I had to leave for work.) But I found the variance of $X_1 - X_2$, which is $3$, and so is the covariance with $X_3$. Do show me your way though. Where do I go from here? How do we go from expectations and covariances to expressions involving the $X$s?

Comment: So if the variance of $X_1-X_2$ is $3$ and the variance of $X_3$ is $3$ and their covariance is $3$ (and their means are $0$), this tells you something helpful.  If you have not spotted it, consider that this implies their correlation is $1$.

Comment: Hm. Introduce matrices $C = [1 \ 0 ]$ and $ K = [ 0 \ 1 ]$. Then we notice that $X_1 - X_2 = C\begin{pmatrix} X_1 - X_2 \\ X_3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $X_3 = K \begin{pmatrix} X_1 - X_2 \\ X_3 \end{pmatrix}$. As such, $X_1 - X_2$ has mean $0$ and variance $3$, while $X_3$ has mean $0$ and variance $3$, by standard calculations. Since these means and variances determine a unique normal distribution, we conclude that $X_1 - X_2 = X_3$. Thus, the subspace we are looking for is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ |  x_1 - x_2 = x_3 \}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  I would have said $X_1-X_2$ and $X_3$ have a correlation of $1$ so are linearly dependent, and they have the same mean and variance so they must be equal with probability $1$, so $X$ must lie on the plane $x_1-x_2-x_3=0$ with probability $1$.